# Call node js function from PugJS?

Tags: javascript, function, express, scope, pug

I am trying to create a button inside PugJS that is clickable (executes JS that is inside node js).

views/index.pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title #{title}
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
  body
    main
      block header
        header.header
          h1 #{title}
      block content
  button(type='submit' onClick='foo();') Click
```

index.js

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    util = require('util'),
    express = require('express'),
    pug = require('pug');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

var foo = function() {
    console.log("foobar");
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {title: "Awesome name", func: foo});
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(200);

  // sending a response does not pause the function
  foo();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const server = app.listen(7000, () => {
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Referencing foo directly just results in "undefined" since the function is undefined in the scope. If I reference "func" via "#{func}" inside index.pug I get errors as well. How do I reference the javascript function inside NodeJS from a button created in PugJS?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a template engine to execute code on the server, that in it self is a huge security risk, template engines are meant to render data server side, so in your situation `foo()` function has to do some operation and pass the result (data) to your pug template the moment your render it ex: res.render`("mytemplate",{foodataL:data})`

Comment: But flash is no longer getting updates, rendering it insecure. Why do I need to use flash for a JS library?

Comment: I think you can use [pug](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) 
 without flash